# What is right way to modify a node field in a multilanguage system (LANGUAGE_NONE or $node->language or ...)

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, i18n-l10n

Let's say we want to modify the body field.

```
$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = "test";
```

This will work if the node is language neutral (?)

```
$node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = "test";
```

This will work if the node has the same langauge as the field.

But is this always the case? I found nodes where this is not the case:

```
(Object) stdClass
...
language (String, 2 characters ) de
...
body (Array, 1 element)
  und (Array, 1 element)
        0 (Array, 5 elements)
            value (String, 4 characters ) test
```

So if this is a correct node, how can we access the body field value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[field_language()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.multilingual.inc/function/field_language/7) returns the field's display language. You should use code similar to the following one:

```
$language = field_language('node', $node, 'body');
do_something_with($node->body[$language][0]);
```

Of course, note that `field_language()` will determine the right display language ('en' or LANGUAGE_NONE or whatever); if you're modifying fields you might want to modify more than one language.

Comment: Does this mean you'd really need to do `foreach($node->field_name as $languaged_field) { ... }` to update them all? Is there nothing more elegant?

Answer (score 5):

What's about getting the field value with `field_get_items()`? Really prefer this solution ...

```
if ($body = field_get_items('node', $node, 'body')) {
  $my_rendered_content = strip_tags(drupal_render(field_view_value('node', $node, 'body', $body[0])));
}
```