# No body text saved when creating a node with I18n and specific language set

Tags: i18n-l10n

Drupal 7

I'm creating a event type nodes, using data from an external database.  It's a multi-lingual site, and the primary language is english.

My code creates the node correctly, when the language is set to LANGUAGE_NONE, but when it is set to "en", the body text is not saved in the database.

```
foreach ($results as $record) {
  echo '<br/>Creating event: ' . $record->name;

  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'event';
  $node->uid = 1;
  node_object_prepare($node);

  $node->title    = $record->name;
  $node->language = "en";
  //$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

  $node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'This is a body text for '.$record->name;
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = 'Here goes a summary for '.$record->name;
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 'raw';

  $path = 'content/programmatically_created_node_' . date('YmdHis');
  $node->path = array('alias' => $path);

  $instance = field_info_instance('node', 'body', 'event');
  print_r($instance);

  $node = node_submit($node);
  node_save($node);  
  dpm($node);
}
```

When $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE, a record is created in the fields_data_body table. I can see the body text, but cannot translate it.  I guess this is correct.

But when $node->language = "en", no record is created.  This is my problem.  I need this set to "en" as it's a multi-lingual site, and without it, there is no "translate" tab when editing the node (Internationalization module drupal.org/project/i18n)

There is some back history to this issue here..  [No "body" when creating a node programatically, with Internationalization](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54596/no-body-when-creating-a-node-programatically-with-internationalization) ..but it's not essential to read it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be showing 'und' for language neutral nodes. Have you checked the value of the $node->language parameter?

You could also try creating one of these nodes with the user interface. Then install the devel module and use the php executor (whatever.com/devel/php) to load the node and output with dpm() to see the contents of the node. You probably have something wrong with the structure.

Example (after the sample node is created):

```
$node = node_load(21);
dpm($node);
```

That will output the node contents for you to help you better explore what you are creating.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I'd forgotten about this problem.  The only solution (i.e. hack) I found was to use node_save(), then re-load the node, set the language to "en", and then node_save() again.  I think there maybe a bug in core or i18n, but it's beyond me to fix it.

Comment: I had a similar problem that was caused by a data migration. I found that I just needed to do a node_load(), copy the body field to the proper language (from $node->body['en'] to $node-body['und']) and set the old language field to NULL. Then run it through node_save().

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was to update the language AFTER it had been saved.

```
$node = node_submit($node);
node_save($node);  

// This is a hack, until a good solution is found.
// Can't successfully set language on create, so update it afterwards
$node = node_load($node->nid);
$node->language = "en";
node_save($node);
```

I know it's a hack. But it will do until a solution is found, or a bug fixed.

Comment: Have you tried this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8404/what-is-right-way-to-modify-a-node-field-in-a-multilanguage-system-language-non. This looks similar to your problem